# Measure DatePicker in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, android-datepicker

In my Xamarin.Android app I need to present DatePicker inside some custom layout.
So I'm trying to calculate how much place will it occupy in order to reorganize other parts of the layout accordingly.
Here is the relevant code:

```
public int pickerHeight(int w, int h)
{
        var  picker = new Android.Widget.DatePicker(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
        var widthMeasureSpec = Android.Views.View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(w, Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
        var heightMeasureSpec = Android.Views.View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(h, Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
        var dp = (picker as Android.Widget.DatePicker);
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        dp.Init(date.Year, date.Month - 1, 1, null);
        picker.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        return picker.MeasuredHeight;
}
```

Unfortunately the height I got in this function is very small and is not really enough for the DatePicker - approx. 200px on the device I'm checking.
In the debugger I've seen that this height corresponds to the height of the upper part of the picker - the TextView showing the current date. The MeasuredHeight of the DayPickerView (the buttons for choosing month and day) is zero. I tried to check the Visibility of these parts in the debugger and they are visible. 
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the `Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.Exactly` mode?

Comment: What about it? If I use it, it returns exactly the dimensions I used while creating the spec. But I want to know how much space is needed for the picker.

Comment: In the activity's `OnWindowFocusChanged` method you can get the height.

Comment: OnFocusChanged is called when everything is already presented on the screen. Too late for me. I want to display the picker inside some (complex) layout and I need to know how much space I need to reserve for it - before the page is displayed.

Comment: Try this `picker.Measure(0,0);`,  replace it with your `picker.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);`

Comment: @Joe Lv I tried this but the result is still the same.